# How to structure the content of EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am making a simple CMS just for learning purposes and I have a question how I would organize it. I have an administration section where you can add new pages, edit content etc, and I also have a public part that the user see for example the pages.

So, I have PageEJB class that has logic for adding a page, edit a page, deleting  a page, finding a page etc. in other words logic from the admin section and public section is in the same class. Should I instead make a PageAdminEJB and PageEJB and separte the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing it for learning purposes only, will you learn anything by having two EJBs instead of one?

I'd say: start with one, see how it grows. When it reaches critical mass (when you see it does too much), refactor it. This way you'll learn how hard/easy is to introduce a new EJB to your system. Perhaps the *facade* design pattern will help you then.

Based on what you wrote, it's difficult to advise decisively one way or the other.

Comment: I thought there must be some common practise on how to organize what goes in different EJBs.

Comment: @BPDeveloper Think of EJBs as of normal classes &mdash; with one distinction: that they can be called across network, which is why they should be coarsely grained. It's hard to say, based on your 2-sentence problem description, what the best way would be for you NOW. This is why I encourage you to start with a simple design, and extend it later.